# Replace one of the segment with a wildcard in a simple way?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have this code in nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/assets/(static|dynamic)/(images|styles|scripts|fonts|videos|audios|var)/(.*) {
    alias /var/web/app1/assets/$1/$2/$3;
    autoindex off;
    expires 366d;
}
```

Now I want to replace the `(images|styles|scripts|fonts|videos|audios|var)` with a wildcard. And everything should continue to work as-is. That is, in that segment, there could be a directory with any name whatsoever.

Is there a simple way to do it in **a simple way**? Preferably without a regexp.

Comment: `location /assets/static/ { root /var/web/app1; ... } location /assets/dynamic/ { root /var/web/app1; ... }` ?

Comment: @jhnc I don't understand

Comment: Rejected suggested revision: `nginxconf` is not supported for syntax highlighting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/168269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace this part `(images|styles|scripts|fonts|videos|audios|var)` with wildcard, you can just remove that part and only keep `(.*)` in location.

Like this:

```
location ~ ^/assets/(static|dynamic)/(.*)$ {
    alias /var/web/app1/assets/$1/$2;
    autoindex off;
    expires 366d;
}
```

Update:
Here is another approach, while keeping 4 segments, but using regex:

```
location ~ ^/assets/(static|dynamic)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ {
    alias /var/web/app1/assets/$1/$2/$3;
    autoindex off;
    expires 366d;
}
```

Comment: Two prefix locations suggested by @jhnc are better in terms of performance.

Comment: that's wrong because I want there to be 4 segments

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes, in terms of performance two separate locations will be a bit faster.

Comment: @Durimar I don't know if it's possible without using regex. but why do you need 4 segments?

Comment: The update (and the original question code) are actually 4 **or more** segments: `.*` can include multiple `/`

Comment: Probably the update still allows access to 3-segment (ie. files directly inside `static` or `dynamic`), as an attacker can just put: `/assets/static//protected.file`. You need something like `^/assets/(static|dynamic)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`